# performance of $interpolate vs ng-repeat and one time binding

Tags: angularjs, performance

At http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135

it is written that for directives it is better to use interpolate than ng-repeat:

> The ng-repeat directive is most likely the worst offender for
>   performance concerns, which means it can easily be abused. An
>   ng-repeat likely deals with Arrays of $scope Objects and this hammers
>   the $digest cycle’s performance.
>
> For example, instead of rendering a global navigation using ng-repeat,
>   we could create our own navigation using the $interpolate provider to
>   render our template against an Object and convert it into DOM nodes.

When using angular 1.3 we could use ng-repeat with one time bindings to achieve the same result.

Is it still better to use $interpolate for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) for this if you're on <1.3, just add `bindonce` next to your `ng-repeat` and change your `ng-*` directives to `bo-*` in the repeating part. It basically does the same thing as 1.3's one time bindings.

If by your quetion you meant should you use `$interpolate` instead of one time binding in 1.3, I'd say go with `ng-repeat` with one time binding since there aren't any watchers to slow you down and it's a lot more readable. Even though `ng-repeat` still creates the child scopes, the performance difference is negligible if you're not doing anything in those scopes.

From experience you'll hit performance issues in your browser in rendering so many elements before `$digest` becomes an issue if you're not checking watchers, even with a lot of child scopes.