# ng-repeat using one-time binding - does track by then have an impact on performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

As I read here ([performance of $interpolate vs ng-repeat and one time binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732602/performance-of-interpolate-vs-ng-repeat-and-one-time-binding)) having the directive `ng-repeat` and use one-time binding is nearly equal in case of performance. Please correct me if this isn't right!

This means, that when using one-time binding on `ng-repeat`, the attribute `track by` doesn't add any value, right? Or does it actually help me in terms of performance, because `ng-repeat` otherwise still would generate an index at `$$hashKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means, that when using one-time binding on ng-repeat, the attribute track by doesn't add any value, right?

There is no correlation between `track by` and one-time binding.

- one-time binding reduces watchers count
- `track by` doesn't re-render DOM once your list is updated from server and their is no change (lets say based on `id` of item)

one-time binding in `ng-repeat` a.e. `ng-repeat="friend in ::friends"` will stop recalculating `friends` once they are stable, which happens after the first digest cycle (if the expression result is a non-undefined value).

For example:

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in ::friends ">{{friend.name}}</li>
```

and:

```
$scope.friends = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Ben'
  }];

  $timeout(function(){
     $scope.friends.push({
    id: 3,
    name: 'Chen'
  });
  },1000);
```

*Result:*

You will see  `Ben` but after 1 second delay there is no change because one-time binding stopped `ng-repeat` watcher. We commonly use it for fixed lists.

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ux5pzLnj/)

BTW, it works for list items count and not on item itself.

---

one-time binding will not get rid of `$$hashKey`

But you can write:

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in ::friends track by friend.id">
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/fj3Ltjwf/)

Comment: Which actually means, that `ng-repeat` (when using one-time binding without `track by`) is doing an overkill by adding an `$$hashKey` property to every object, because the list isn't watched once it's considered stable, right?

Comment: @SimonSimCity not at all, one-time binding will remove watch from `ng-repeat` items count. so if you will add/remove new item - nothing will happen. On other side  `track by` will not re-render DOM of your items **content** if id of the item stay the same

Comment: I agree. So, the generation of `$$hashKey` is not unnecessary when using one-time bindings, but needed to stabilize the view (ensure data hasn't changed between two `$digest`-cycles). After this, the watchers are removed and no new items or their change in order will be recognized. Means `friend in ::friends` will still have to create the `$$hashKey`, and therefore adding `track by` here will also improve performance here, right?